# Delete column from 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a quesion that I found in internet but it was not has best solution. My question is that I have one 2D matrix and I want to delete one column at ith position. Example the matrix can be represent as A[2][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6}. And I want to delete the column at postion 2. So the output is B={1,3,4,6}. Can you help me please?

```
A=[1 2 3
   4 5 6]
```

The output

```
   B=[1 3
      4 6]
```

The function is

```
int** delete_column(int** inputMatrix,int position)
{
  //The size of outMatrix must be smaller than inputMatrix

  return outMatrix;
}
```

Comment: free the memory at `inputMatrix[position]` and copy `inputMatrix[i] = inputMatrix[i + 1]` for i from `position` to two less than size. Also, your function should actually get the size of the matrix.

Comment: @Shahbaz  it will be more like shift all the elements after the given column one position to the left and then free the memory for the last element. You can not free the memory in the middle of an array.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, Oh wait, right. What I do is actually remove one row (assuming `inputMatrix[i]` selects row `i`). If the matrix selects first on row and then on coloumn, there's no way but to actually copy the data.

Comment: "Can you help me please" is not a question about a programming language.

Comment: You can get it from here - "C++ for Scientiﬁc Computing" (http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/richardsonm/cpp.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this in-place with static arrays in c++. You will need to create another array and copy data there. If you use an array of pointers to dynamic arrays however, you can move the elements in-place and than call `realloc` to shrink the arrays. You can Also use a vector of vectors and call remove on them.

Comment: I think I can copy to other matrix that has smaller size than orginal matrix. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes you can by writing a double for cycle.

Comment: No sensible implementation would copy the entire matrix every time, especially for a shrinking operation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit do you see an alternative if static array is used?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Of course - leave empty space at the end. It'll almost certainly be reclaimed in short order by an _insert_ operation anyway.